# java script order of execution

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, promise

I have this piece of code:

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');

async function getAWSKeys(){
  AWS.config.update({ region: 'us-west-2' });
  const SSM = new AWS.SSM();
  
  let ssAccessKeyPath = '/ss/s3/aws_access_key_id';
  let ssSecretKeyPath = '/ss/s3/aws_secret_access_key';
  
  console.log('before');
  const params = await SSM.getParameters({Names: [ssSecretKeyPath, ssAccessKeyPath], WithDecryption: true}).promise();
  console.log('after');
  return params;
}

var parameters = getAWSKeys();
console.log('1');
console.log('2');
console.log('3');
console.log(parameters);
```

When I run *node index.js* The log console shows:

```
before
1
2
3
Promise { <pending> }
after
```

My function *getAWSKeys* is *async*, and I'm using *await* for the call to *SSM.getParameters*. I really expect:

```
before
after
1
2
3
'my params'
```

Why execution doesn't wait for *SSM.getParameters*?

Comment: You're not `await`ing `getAWSKeys`.

Comment: `await` doesn't pause execution, the code is still asynchronous. It might help you understand it better if you replaced `await` with `.then()` callbacks

Comment: thanks to all of you. I'm new to promises and js. How to use 'then()' exactly?

Comment: Using then() is a fundamental part of using promises and will be covered in every basic promises tutorial as well as in documentation. If I were you I would forget that await exists for a while until you really can conquer using promises

Comment: I will reply my own answer. I have found a way to accomplish what I need. Anyaway, please post your answers guys, they really helped me, I will vote up.